# In Visual Studio 2008, is it possible to mix vertical tab groups with horizontal tab groups?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, multiple-monitors

I have a 1920x1200 screen an would like to customize VS2008 code windows to have some areas split vertically and horizontally (tab groups).

I can only seem to do all vertical or all horizontal in VS2008. Is there any crafty way of getting a mixing both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible in Visual Studio.  However, you should check out this nice product for splitting applications:  http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/